# trouble in sending google map location through sms

Tags: android, google-maps, sms, android-contacts

i am working my application in which i have to send my google map location on the click of button.I followed several tutorials but they all are using SMSManager which is already deprecated.
I am using this to send a sms

```
String smsNumber = tab.getText().toString();
                        String smsText = "I am in danger.Please follow my location ... ";

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                        intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

and this for the google map location

```
Intent intentgooglemaps = new Intent(
                                android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/?"));
                        startActivity(intentgooglemaps);
```

what still confusing me is: how to send the google map location just after the message that i have typed.

i am fetching contacts from the phone-book using :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);
```